# Is the zip python function capable to use an entire matrix as index?

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, neural-network

I was analyzing a chunk of code and I got stuck on an application of zip function that I don't understand.
The code is extracted from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFqigdDW4Uk&t=885s

The algorithm consists of NN applied to a noised version of the fashion MNIST dataset with the goal to clean up the images.

After the training phase and the application of the model to a sample of 10 images, I want to show 3 different kinds of pictures.
X_actual, noisy_image, and denoised_image after the application of the NN.

The images are represented in 3 different matrices. Each of the matrices is (row=number of images, columns= number of pixels ).
To plot a fig of (3,10) the code is using the following instructions:

```
fig,axes=plt.subplots(nrows=3,ncols=10,sharex=True,sharey=True,figsize=(20,4))
for images, row in zip ([X_actual,noisy_image,denoised_image],axes):
    for img,ax in zip(images,row):
        ax.imshow(img.reshape((28,28)), cmap='Greys_r')
        ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
```

From this, it seems the zip function can use as an iteration index even a matrix and this is a little bit confusing for me. Am I correct in thinking this? I can understand when zip iterate through two lists but this is different.

Comment: `zip` just iterates over whatever you give it. As long as it's iterable it will work. Often something iterable can be converted into a `list`. What happens if you convert `X_actual` to a `list`, or `axes[0]` to a `list`?

Comment: I see your point what I dont understand is that images is the index over 3 matrices. How can shape 3 matrices as a list? Something like having a list of rows?

Comment: “`images` is an index over 3 matrices” I don’t know what you mean. `images` will be a single value from your list, eg `X_actual`. Maybe a better name for it would be `image`, but I don’t know, you don’t specify what `X_actual` actually is.

Comment: When running the iteration I associate the 3 different matrices with 3 different figures in the plot. Given that each row of the matrices represents an image that has been flattened. in the row I was asking how it is possible to choose the 1st row, then the 2nd row etc etc? It seems that with zip we pick up the entire X_actual and not it row by row. Probably this is made by the second zip in the code